# See dependency tree for single configuration in gradle (using `dependencies` task)

Tags: java, groovy, gradle

Whenever I call `gradlew dependencies` on a gradle project, I get a list of every configuration's dependencies (which when only compile is configured, usually includes the same thing repeated several times for runtime, test and testRuntime).

Is there a way to specify a particular configuration to view the dependencies of?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to filter by module as well, you can use the following command:

```
gradlew -p <module-name> dependencies --configuration <configuration-name>
```

So for example, if you want to output all dependency graphs use:

```
gradlew dependencies
```

So for example, if you want to output all dependency graphs for a `lib` module use:

```
gradlew -p lib dependencies
```

If you want to output compile dependencies for debug variant:

```
gradlew dependencies --configuration debugCompileClasspath
```

If you want to output runtime dependencies for debug variant:

```
gradlew dependencies --configuration debugRuntimeClasspath
```

If you want to output runtime dependencies for debug variant and production flavor in the `lib` module:

```
gradlew -p lib dependencies --configuration productionDebugRuntimeClasspath
```

Answer (score 15):

The command is: `gradle[w] dependencies --configuration <configuration_name>`

In my case, I want to see just compile configuration so I would type:

```
gradlew dependencies --configuration compile
```

Comment: For a gradle Android project you could simply call  `./gradlew app:dependencies` from the root directory